# C++ Design: Passing pointer/reference to ref-counted object

Tags: c++, parameters, c++11, shared-ptr

I have a directed acyclic graph, composed of Node objects. Each node has a list of `std::shared_ptr`s to other nodes, which are its children in the graph. I have lots of useful methods I need, such as inserting/emplacing/reparenting nodes, testing if a node is an ancestor of another, etc. Some are standard STL-like methods, and some are specific to directed acyclic graphs and specific to my needs.

The question is, When such a method takes a node as a parameter, should it take a reference? of a `weak_ptr`? or a `shared_ptr`? I tried to examine use cases but it's hard to tell. What's the best design here? I'm new to smart pointers and I'm not sure what's the best choice. Should I treat `shared_ptr<Node>` as "the representation" of node objects? Or maybe the way to choose is more sophisticated?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only pass a `shared_ptr` (by value) or copy it when the set of owners is meaningfully extended. It's safe, and preferred, to pass pointers when dealing with nodes as pure information.

Note the `std::enable_shared_from_this` facility to retrieve the correct `std::shared_ptr` from any graph object. With that base class, a valid naked pointer and a shared pointer are essentially equivalent. I'm not sure how much, if any, overhead it adds. (It definitely ensures that there will be no additional heap fragmentation, which `std::make_shared` also does.)

Passing `shared_ptr` anywhere is just an optimization of functionality elegantly provided by `shared_from_this`. But when you do, pass them by `const` reference, since they are just providing information without actively arbitrating ownership.

Comment: I see... I didn't realize weak ptrs don't have operator->, so passing them is useless as I'd have to convert to shared ptr before doing anything with them in most methods